# How do I replace values in a column in KNIME?

Tags: knime

I have a column of countries with 50 different values that I want to reduce to United States and Other.

1. Can someone help me with that?
2. Another example is Age which has 48 values that I'd like to reduce to only 4 like 1 to 18 = youth, 18-27 = starting, etc.

I've actually got about 5 columns that I want to reduce the values of. So would I need to repeat the process multiple times in KNIME or can I accomplish multiple column value replacements at once?

Answer (score 3):

The latter on can easily be achieved with the Rule Engine

```
$Col0$ > 1 AND $Col0$ <18 => "youth"
```

For the First problem I'd use a `String Replace (Dictionary)`.

I don't think you replace all at once but you can loop over columns.

Comment: Can you explain the String Replace (Dictionary)? Am I supposed to build a text file with the values I want? Also, the Rule Engine worked perfect. Thank you

Comment: Yes you have to create such a file.

Comment: I think Rule Engine should work for the first one too: just make a rule or rules that catches all the `United States` values, then a final 'default' rule of `TRUE => "Other"`.

Answer (score 2):

For the second case I would use [Numeric Binner](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.binner.BinnerNodeFactory):

> For each column a number of intervals - known as bins - can be
>   defined. Each of these bins is given a unique name (for this column),
>   a defined range, and open or closed interval borders. They
>   automatically ensure that the ranges are defined in descending order
>   and that interval borders are consistent. In addition, each column is
>   either replaced with the binned, string-type column, or a new binned,
>   string-type column is appended.